How to fix WebAuth refusal to authenticate enrollment made with Mobile devices
I am setting up web authentication for my project and when I start enrollement on the web, it allows me create passkey with my Android device and also log in using the same device. Unfortunately, when the enrolment is done via the Android device itself, the registration process completes successfully but the authentication fails by issuing no passkey available. I believe the issue has to do with the parameters but I do not know what I am doing wrongly. Can someone point me in the right direction?
This is the parameters I send along for both registration and authentication
function getGetParams(page){
    // Check and create variables
    if(page=='login'){
        var uName=$('#user-email').val();
        var uDisp=$('#uid-name').val();
    }else{
        var uName=$('#disp-uid-email').text();
        var uDisp=$('#disp-uid-name').text();
    }

    // Define parameters
    let url = '&apple=0&yubico=0&solo=0&hypersecu=0&google=0&microsoft=0&mds=0';
        url += '&requireResidentKey=0&type_usb=1&type_nfc=1&type_ble=1&type_int=1&type_hybrid=1';
        url += '&fmt_android-key=1&fmt_android-safetynet=1&fmt_apple=1&fmt_fido-u2f=1&fmt_none=1&fmt_packed=1&fmt_tpm=1';
        url += '&rpId=';
        url += '&userId=DEFAULT';
        url += '&userName=' + uName;
        url += '&userDisplayName=' + uDisp;
        url += '&userVerification=discouraged';
        return url;
}


This code has nothing directly to do with with webauthn.

You need to set residentKey: "required" in authenticatorSelection in order to create a passkey.

@Tim Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. Stay blessed

@Evert in setting up web authentication, you need to pass parameters from the client side as well as the various function calls that needs to communicate with the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

@BigPee i get that, but all of this is implementation specific. Glad you figured it out though!

To resolve this issue, I needed need to set residentKey: "required" in authenticatorSelection in order to create a passkey on the device. In the function residentKey was set to 0 and that caused the passkey not to be saved on the Android even though the registration was successful. Finally, I needed to set the value to 1 to make it work.
// Define parameters
let url = '&apple=0&yubico=0&solo=0&hypersecu=0&google=0&microsoft=0&mds=0';
    url += '&requireResidentKey=1&type_usb=1&type_nfc=1&type_ble=1&type_int=1&type_hybrid=1';
    url

